how do I make my app into apk using flutter
I am trying to make my app into apk, but whenever I run flutter build apk --release, this error shows up
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':audioplayers' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.32

This error shows up

Can you share your pubspec.yaml file?

Flutter apps require a minimum of Kotlin Plugin 1.5.3 to run
To fix this you can do the following
Open /android/build.gradle, and change ext.kotlin_version:
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50' // Remove this.    
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31' // Add this

More solutions and information about this can be found here

I am using project IDX, and I cant seem to find the buildscript, Ive checked both the android build gradle, and the app gradle, is there other build.gradle that I should check?
here's the files of my app: https://postimg.cc/k6X4cfJk

Can you add both your app level and project level build.gradle files, by editing the question.
